# Ceph OSDs are full, but I have not stored that much of data

Tags: ceph, capacity

I have a Ceph cluster running with 18 X 600GB OSDs. There are three pools (size:3, pg_num:64) with an image size of 200GB on each, and there are 6 servers connected to these images via iSCSI and storing about 20 VMs on them. Here is the output of "ceph df":

POOLS:

```
POOL                           ID     STORED      OBJECTS     USED        %USED      MAX AVAIL 
cephfs_data                     1         0 B           0         0 B          0           0 B 
cephfs_metadata                 2      17 KiB          22     1.5 MiB     100.00           0 B 
defaults.rgw.buckets.data       3         0 B           0         0 B          0           0 B 
defaults.rgw.buckets.index      4         0 B           0         0 B          0           0 B 
.rgw.root                       5     2.0 KiB           5     960 KiB     100.00           0 B 
default.rgw.control             6         0 B           8         0 B          0           0 B 
default.rgw.meta                7       393 B           2     384 KiB     100.00           0 B 
default.rgw.log                 8         0 B         207         0 B          0           0 B 
rbd                             9     150 GiB      38.46k     450 GiB     100.00           0 B 
rbd3                           13     270 GiB      69.24k     811 GiB     100.00           0 B 
rbd2                           14     150 GiB      38.52k     451 GiB     100.00           0 B
```

Based on this, I expect about 1.7 TB RAW capacity usage, BUT it is currently about 9TBs!

RAW STORAGE:

```
CLASS     SIZE        AVAIL       USED        RAW USED     %RAW USED 
hdd       9.8 TiB     870 GiB     9.0 TiB      9.0 TiB         91.35 
TOTAL     9.8 TiB     870 GiB     9.0 TiB      9.0 TiB         91.35
```

And the cluster is down because there is very few capacity remained. I wonder what makes this and how can I get it fixed.
Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was mounting the iSCSI target without **discard** option.

Since I am using RedHat Virtualization, I just modified all storage domains created on top of Ceph, and enabled "discard" on them[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOhNu.png). Just after a few hours, about 1 TB of storage released. Now it is about 12 hours passed and 5 TB of storage is released.
Thanks